# RSpec with my custom error class

Tags: ruby, rspec

In RSPec I have this:

```
expect{obj.my_method}.to raise_error(Module::Error::MyErrorClass)
```

and my test is failing with following:

```
expected Module::Error::MyErrorClass, got #<RuntimeError: My error message.
```

I want something like

```
expect{obj.my_method}.to raise_error(Module::Error::MyErrorClass.message)
```

but in that case test just fails without any particular message. How can I make it pass?

My error class looks like:

```
module Module
  module Error
    class MyErrorClass < StandardError
      def self.message
        raise "My error message."
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Don't raise in `message`. It's already an error object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error class's `message` method should simply [define a string](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Exception.html#method-i-message) - i.e.

```
module Module
  module Error
    class MyErrorClass < StandardError
      def message
        "My error message."
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now, assuming this exception is actually getting raised, any of the following should work:

```
expect{obj.my_method}.to raise_error(Module::Error::MyErrorClass)
expect{obj.my_method}.to raise_error(Module::Error::MyErrorClass.new.message)
expect{obj.my_method}.to raise_error("My error message.")
expect{obj.my_method}.to raise_error(Module::Error::MyErrorClass, "My error message.")
```

([Link](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher) to RSpec docs for this matcher.)

Comment: Thanks. I did as you said, without self and without raise in a message method. I am calling it in the program as: (a <= b) ? true : (raise Module::Error::MyErrorClass.new.message) but still test fails with the same message: expected Module::Error::MyErrorClass, got #<RuntimeError: My error message.

Comment: Actually now it passes, it is ok. I forgot to add 'new' in RSpec test in Module::Error::MyErrorClass.new.message after the changes. Thank you!

Comment: But should I see "my error message" in console after test passes? At the moment it doesn't give me any message, only "0 failures".

Comment: This is getting a bit beyond the scope of the original question, but... No, it's correct that you'll see nothing. Normally, if any exception gets raised within a test then the test fails. However, by wrapping the code in a block (`expect { ... }`) you are telling it to *expect* an exception and therefore gracefully handle it.